# Using localStorage in webView across remote and local pages

Tags: android, local-storage, android-webview

I am not very experienced with Android dev, but I am very experienced with web dev. I am creating a fairly simple webview-based app to our mobile site. The webview app I have so far basically works fine, actually. When the app launches, it detects if the network is connected.

If yes, it opens webview to a remote URL at our server. This works great. The page on our remote server saves some data to localStorage. This also works fine and correctly in a 'normal' browser.

If no network access, the app loads a local page into webview. I have an "assets/html" folder in the app with local HTML/JS/CSS. The local page itself loads fine, but invoking localStorage through JS does not see the data saved when the app was online.

Should this work? Should this not? I don't know enough about Android webView to even know if this principle is sound.

Basically, I want data saved to localStorage when the webview app is online and hitting our server, and then to read this localStorage from local pages saved inside the app.

The remote page can read and write to localStorage within the webView app perfectly fine. The local page cannot see localStorage data, even though it is loaded in the same webview app.

These are the permissions in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And these are my webview settings in java:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```